# regex to update symfony render tag signature after update

Tags: regex, symfony, twig

After symfony update the render tag signature has changed (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md):

Before:

```
{% render 'BlogBundle:Post:list' with { 'limit': 2 }, { 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error' } %}
```

After:

```
{% render controller('BlogBundle:Post:list', { 'limit': 2 }), { 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error' } %}
{# Or: #}
{{ render(controller('BlogBundle:Post:list', { 'limit': 2 }), { 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error'}) }}
```

I'm looking for a way to modify my calls automatically using some regular expression.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the input, and what's the desired output? Sorry, but not clear to me from your question. :)

Comment: Is it really worth that? How many places in your code must be fixed?

Comment: 'BlogBundle:Post:list', 'limit': 2, 'alt': 'BlogBundle:Post:error' are optional inputs. and I've got about 50 entries that needs to be fixed. Also when switching to new version live I want to have as less downtime as possible.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
\{% render ([^,%]*?), ([^%]*?)%\}
```

with:

```
{% render controller(\1), \2%}
```

Comment: This assumes there is always a comma and (exactly) two parts that need to be replaced. it works for your example, but you should probably check in case you have other forms of input.